# Azure Service Bus Continuous WebJob pause

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

Is there a way to pause a continuous webjob - to stop receive messages from the service bus for time interval?
I have a system that is receiving post data constantly. Then the posted data is send to the Service Bus. I am wondering if there is a way to stop processing the messages. Of course the other solution would be not to send those messages - keep them in a queue in the sender system.

Comment: i'd guessing something like creating a time frame and checking if the time frame matches current time and not doing anything if it does match

Comment: yes but if I do that I am still receiving the message. Seems like not the most elegant solution. Maybe best is not even to send the message but I am wondering if there is better way as I do not want to spend time to implement queueing mechanism

Comment: Is your webjob use servicebustrigger ?

Comment: no it is continuous and is triggered by Service Bus message

Answer (score 2):

You already have the queuing mechanism... the Service Bus. It sounds like you are declaratively connecting to the queue by using the ServiceBusTrigger attribute. i.e.

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
```

But this isn't the only way to receive a message in a continuous webjob. You can use a QueueClient object to receive these messages just as easily:

```
var connectionString = "//connection string here//";
var queueName = "samplequeue";

var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(cnStr, queueName);

client.OnMessage(message =>
{
   string msg = message.GetBody<string>();
   // Process message here...
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

(See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues for more information.)

So in your webjob, you can listen to two busses: the first is the operational bus you are already using to process your business messages. The new topic is a control bus. It's always listening, but you only send it a message when you wish to change the behavior of the operational queue.

So you send "START" to the control bus. Receipt of that message would invoke the code above and cause the operational bus to start processing messages.

If you want to stop processing, send "STOP" to the control bus. When this message is received, call `client.Close();` on the operational bus. This pauses processing of the messages until the next "START" message is received.

Of course, you can expand on this. You could, for instance send "PAUSE 10 MINUTES" to the control bus, which could stop the operational bus, and then set a timer to restart it 10 minutes later. You're limited only by your imagination!

Personally, I would likely use Json messages rather than plain text, but whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could stop the webjob by setting WEBJOBS_STOPPED to 1 in your application settings. That is a bit crude, but it stops the webjob.